# Concatenar letra por letra cuando hago una acción por el teclado Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

Practicando Javascript me encuentro con una dificultad a la hora de concatenar caracteres. Quiero hacer que cada vez que yo presione la tecla '.' (punto) me escriba lo que tengo en la variable texto, pero de forma tal que lo haga letra por letra, es decir la variable tiene el texto "Hola", entonces al presionar la primera vez la tecla '.'(punto) en el input me debe aparecer la 'H', luego cuando yo vuelva a presionar la tecla '.'(punto) me debe aparecer la siguiente letra, 'o', y así sucesivamente hasta completar la palabra, pero mi problema es que yo al presionar el punto me esta apareciendo toda la cadena y no logro entender como puedo hacer que lo haga letra por letra.

```js
const inputTexto = document.getElementById("input-texto")

var texto = "Hola"

function presionarTecla (){
    var codigo = event.keyCode
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(codigo));
        for (let i=0; i<texto.length; i++) {
            if (String.fromCharCode(codigo) == '.'){
            inputTexto.value += texto[i]
        }
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practicando Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <div id="segundoDiv">
  
        <br>
        <label for="">Ingrese texto: </label> <br>
        <input id="input-texto" onkeypress="presionarTecla()" type="text"><br>
      
    </div>


</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: En esta linea ```inputTexto.value += texto[i]``` no tienes que concatenarlo todo, sino solo una letra. Como? depende de ti, lo mas facil un contador interno y un substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que concatenas todo la palabra debes concatenar solo una letra.

Esta linea es el problema:

```
inputTexto.value += texto[i]
```

Como lo arreglamos?

1. Crea una variable temporal, esta llevara la cuenta de la letra que se mostrara.
2. Concatena un `substring` de la palabra usando la variable anterior.

---

Ejemplo

```
var texto = "Hola";
var contador = 0;

function presionarTecla (){
    var codigo = event.keyCode
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(codigo));
    for (let i=0; i<texto.length; i++) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(codigo) == '.'){
            inputTexto.value += texto.substring(contador+1, contador);
            contador++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No logro entender el ejemplo, por que seguiría actuando de la misma forma, es decir me está concatenando toda la palabra entera.

Comment: Había un problema, el if iba primero y después el for, ahora surgió otro problema donde cada vez que presiono la tecla punto me devuelve la primera letra pero repetida segun la cantidad de letras que tiene el texto, voy a ver si puedo seguir arreglando

Comment: Solucionado había que colocar i<1 en el for para que lo haga una vez la letra. Gracias por guiarme!